# Clear Activity backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I have an application structure which is something like this:

1 [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

n [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

The App flow is something like this:

(Activity 1)(Fragment A) => (Activity 1)(Fragment B) => (Activity 1)(Fragment C) => ...

So, multiple instances of a single activity class are instantiated, with different Fragments in them.

Also, when I am in Fragment B (suppose), I do a fragment transaction to [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) it with Fragment B', so no new Activity is created and Fragment B is replaced with Fragment B'.

Now, on this transaction, I want the activity containing Fragment A and all other previously launched activities to pop off the [backstack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Intent flags can be used([CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) to open root activities, but here I am doing a [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#q=fragment%20transaction) and want to clear the activity backstack on this event.

Any help ?

How to clear activity backstack without using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, because I am not doing an Intent call here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store static reference to activity A in his class. When you need to remove A from history you just call ActivityA.getInstance().finish();

If you has more that one inctance on A activity put references to it in Vector and finish using ActivityA.getInstance(0).finish();

Comment: No! Keeping static reference to Activity contexts, am not doing memory leaks now, it would be better if there is an API method for this.

Comment: You may store WeakReference to you activity instances. May be it prewent leaks. Vector<WeakReference<ActivityA>> instances;

Comment: I don't know such method. In my practice I use one activity and a lot of fragments.